# Accessing HBase tables through Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hbase

I am using this code-example http://www.vidyasource.com/blog/Programming/Scala/Java/Data/Hadoop/Analytics/2014/01/25/lighting-a-spark-with-hbase to read a hbase table using Spark with the only change of adding the hbase.zookeeper.quorum through code as it is not picking it from the hbase-site.xml.

Spark 1.5.3
HBase 0.98.0

I am facing this error -

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: com/google/protobuf/HBaseZeroCopyByteString
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.RequestConverter.buildRegionSpecifier(RequestConverter.java:921)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.RequestConverter.buildGetRowOrBeforeRequest(RequestConverter.java:132)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.getRowOrBefore(ProtobufUtil.java:1520)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(ConnectionManager.java:1294)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1128)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1111)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1070)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.finishSetup(HTable.java:347)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:201)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:159)
at test.MyHBase.getTable(MyHBase.scala:33)
at test.MyHBase.<init>(MyHBase.scala:11)
at $line43.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.fetch(<console>:30)
at $line44.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:49)
at $line44.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:49)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:370)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:742)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1194)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:308)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1194)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:300)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1194)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:287)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1194)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:905)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:905)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1848)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1848)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Seems like your are hitting [HBASE-10304](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-10304). It is fixed in 0.99.0 release. Also see [HBASE-11118](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-11118)

Comment: Yes, seems like it. I didnt find a workaround for SPARK in there. Most of them are for hadoop jobs. @Sumit Do you know if there is a workaround for this with hbase 0.98.0 ? (upgrading is not an option for me right now)

Answer (score 2):

This is an HBase issue tracked and fixed in [HBASE-10304](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-10304). The problem is that the `HBaseZeroCopyByteString` class is declared to be in the Protobuf library, but it's in a different jar file. In the end a different classloader loads it and cannot find the superclass declaration. It is fixed in HBase 0.99.

I think a workaround may be to make sure you include with the jars you submit to Spark the jars that contain `com.google.protobuf.LiteralByteString` and `com.google.protobuf.HBaseZeroCopyByteString`.

In the end you should really upgrade. Can you imagine the list of bugs that have been fixed since 0.98? Do you plan to hit them all and work around them one by one?

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I am aware it is because of HBASE-10304 bug. I tried to add the hbase-protocol.jar to the driver-classpath but that only work in yarn-client mode when I collect all the keys (i use to query hbase) on the driver and then query hbase. (and none of this works in yarn-cluster mode even if  i collect the keys on driver before querying)

Comment: That suggests that the right jars are present on the local machine but do not get distributed to the executors. Are you using `spark-submit` and specifying the jars with `--jars`? I wonder what may be going wrong... You could perhaps try running `hadoop classpath` and adding all that to `--jars` as well. This would ensure that the same jars are used on the executors as on the local machine.

Comment: "Are you using spark-submit and specifying the jars with --jars?" - Yes and I
tried adding all the jars from hadoop classpath but still the same error. I also have the hbase-protocol on both executor and driver classpath using - `spark.executor.extraClassPath        /apache/hbase/lib/hbase-protocol-0.98.0-EBAY-21.jar
spark.driver.extraClassPath        /apache/hbase/lib/hbase-protocol-0.98.0-EBAY-21.jar`

Comment: To get a better understanding of what happens, maybe try printing `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` on the driver (simple `println`) and on the executor (`sc.parallelize(Seq(1)).foreach { _ => println(...) }`) and see if the difference explains something. A worrying possibility is that there are multiple classloaders in play and it's not as simple as a classpath issue.

Comment: Crazy. I'm just clutching at straws... You could try printing `classOf[com.google.protobuf.HBaseZeroCopyByteString].getClassLoader` and also for `LiteralByteString` on both the driver and the executor to see if that explains something. Actually accessing `HBaseZeroCopyByteString` on the executor should fail. If it does not fail, that would be an interesting clue. It would suggest that the error you see does not come from the normal executor environment but from somewhere else. (PS: You still don't want to upgrade HBase? :))

Comment: Thanks Daniel for all the help. I think I will just wait for the upgrade. Nothing worked with 0.98.0 unfortunately.